# Pattern matching some lists -- different cases

Tags: list, prolog, pattern-matching, unification

Different cases with lists.If those cases (a) until (h) work or not.If work then the results should be given.What i did was to

```
(a) ?- [s,u,b,s,t,i,t,u,t,e]=[H1,H2|T].
My answer  is H1=[s] ,H2=[u,b,s,t,i,t,u,t], T=[e]
(b)?- [substitute]=[H1|T].
My answer is wrong it cant be done
(c) ?- [[substitute]]=[H1|T].
My answer is H1=[substitute] T=[]
(d)?- [[s,u,b,s],[t,i,t,u,t,e]=[H1|T].
My answer is H1=[s,u,b,s] and T=[t,i,t,u,t,e]
(e)?- [[s,u,b,s], t,i,t,u,t,e]=[H1|T].
My answer is wrong the tail has issues
(f) ?- [[s,u,b,s],[t,i,t,u,t,e]]=[H1,H2|T].
My answer is H1=[s,u,b,s] H2=[t,i,t,u,t,e] T=[]
(g) ?- [[s,u,b,s],[t,i,t,u,t,e]]=[[H1,H2],H3|T].
My answer is wrong
(e)?- f1(a,Y,,f(Z,2))=f1[a,[1,2],f(1,Y)).
first time i see something like this i don't know
(h)?- f2(A,B,C)=f2(a,[1,2,f(1,Y)]).
same as here
```

Comment: You can easily check your answers by typing the queries in a prolog interpreter. When you have a specific doubt we can help to clarify that.

Comment: yes but i will write in pencil so i could not

Comment: (a) incorrect, (b) incorrect, (c) correct, (d) the expression is a syntax error, (e) incorrect, (f) correct, (g) incorrect, (e) [second (e)] the expression is a syntax error, (h) Prolog term unification `f2(...)` unifies with `f2(...)` if you can unify the arguments. They must have covered basic Prolog terms in your class.

Comment: why are incorrect?

Comment: Sometimes you are interpreting the list syntax correctly and sometimes not. Examine your lists carefully. Note that `[H1, H2|T]` is a list whose first two elements are `H1` and `H2` and then `T` is a list that is the "rest of the list". Also note that if you have `[[a,b], [c], d, e, [f,g,h]]` that is a list of 5 elements. Those elements are `[a,b]`, `[c]`, `d`, `e`, and `[f,g,h]`. You should be able to figure it out from there. `[[H1,H2],H3|T]` is a list whose first two elements are `[H1,H2]` and `H3`. `[H1,H2]` is a list of 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Unification is about matching up the corresponding parts of terms.

```
(a) ?- [ s , u ,   b,s,t,i,t,u,t,e  ] =
       [ s , u  | [b,s,t,i,t,u,t,e] ] =
       [ H1, H2 | T                 ] 

(b) ?- [ substitute      ] =
       [ substitute | [] ] =
       [ H1         | T  ] 

(c) ?- [ [substitute]      ] =
       [ [substitute] | [] ] =
       [ H1           | T  ]

(d) ?- [ [s,u,b,s] ,   [t,i,t,u,t,e]   ] =
       [ [s,u,b,s] | [ [t,i,t,u,t,e] ] ] =
       [ H1        | T                 ]

(e) ?- [ [s,u,b,s] ,  t,i,t,u,t,e  ] =
       [ [s,u,b,s] | [t,i,t,u,t,e] ] =
       [ H1        | T             ]

(f) ?- [ [s,u,b,s] , [t,i,t,u,t,e]      ] =
       [ [s,u,b,s] , [t,i,t,u,t,e] | [] ] =
       [ H1        , H2            | T  ]

(g) ?- [ [s , u , b, s ], [t,i,t,u,t,e]      ] =
       [ [s , u , b, s ], [t,i,t,u,t,e] | [] ] =
       [ [H1,H2 ]       , H3            | T  ]       % fails!

(e) ?- f1( a, Y    , f(Z, 2)) =
       f1( a, [1,2], f(1, Y)) 

(h) ?- f2( A, B            , C) =
       f2( a, [1,2,f(1,Y)] )                          % fails!
```